# Supreme and Infimus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I need to know why this happens ...

Reading a book just find that $$\sup_{y \in [0,2\pi]} \left \{ \inf_{x \in [0,2\pi]} \sin(x+y)  \right \}=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

The infimum of $\sin(x+y)$ is a number, not an expression with a $y$ in it, hence the supremum there is

$\sup\{-1\}=-1$

Comment: Thx... Easy way is always the correct...

Comment: As a side note, this question gets much more interesting if the intervals for both $x$ and $y$ are less than a full period of $\sin$.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the value chosen for $y$, $\sin(x+y)$ varies over its entire range of $[-1,1]$ if $x$ is allowed to range over a full period $[0,2\pi]$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\inf_{x \in [0,2\pi]} \sin(x+y) = -1
\end{align*}
for every $y$. The supremum of the singleton $\{-1\}$ is of course $-1$. Hence
\begin{align*}
\sup_{y \in [0,2\pi]} \left\{ \inf_{x \in [0,2\pi]} \sin(x+y) \right\} = -1
\end{align*}